# C# How to windows impersonate over distributed system?

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation, sspi

I have distributed system, in which I access some internal network resource through Windows Authentication:

> 1. User #345 request -> MyWebInterface -> SerializableQueue -> Worker #123
> 2. Worker #123 access resource through WinAuth (currently under service account, not from user account).
> 3. User #345 response <- MyWebInterface <- SerializableQueue <- Worker #123

The problem is in **step 2** - I need to impersonate under User #345 and then access resource. This is security requirement to use this resource.

How one should serialize user credentials and then deserialize them at worker to accomplish WinAuth impersonation?

Comment: AFAIK as long as User #345 does not provide his username and password, you can't.

Comment: Carefully consider if the "security requirement" is correct in this case. Giving a process the ability to impersonate arbitrary users, aside from being difficult to do, has big implications for security, in that it makes things *less* secure rather than *more*. You are almost always better off giving the service unrestricted access, but having it validate the user's access against the resource explicitly. This only requires the user's validated identity, not their credentials.

Comment: @JeroenMostert currently only available option to check permissions is through impersonation. There is no API for explicit checks, so I can only accomplish impersonation and "run-to-check" them. Worker has no right to access resource, neither should have any, it should be capable of accomplish some work on-behalf of user. This is sad, I know, but can't do much about other team projects.

Comment: Then you have the unenviable task of essentially doing Kerberos all over again. Normally you would use Kerberos constrained delegation, but since the work is queued, that would mean holding on to a ticket that might expire. Keep in mind that if a service is capable of accomplishing "some" work on behalf of the user, it can do *anything* on behalf of the user. This is typically much more sensitive and open to abuse than whatever privileges the service would have on the resource -- a vulnerability in the service gives away the keys to the kingdom, rather than the keys to the resource.

Comment: Although I agree with you, but generally user enters username/password in windows on startup, so he already had given the keys, they obscured-scrumbled by third authority but remain as keys. The question is why those keys can't be rechecked again in chain. Google does this by asking you for grant-permission, rather than asking you to retype password. As I see, windows can't do the same thing.

Comment: It can -- this is called a [ticket-granting ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/secauthn/ticket-granting-tickets) (which is still not the user's actual credentials, though, scrambled or not, as those would have unlimited validity). But once you start digging in to this you'll get deep into the guts of Kerberos, with things that are not neatly exposed by an API in Win32/.NET itself. For a more open approach you run into things like Active Directory Federated Services (no experience myself).

Comment: Bottom line, if you can get the user to explicitly give their credentials to you, you can devise some way of storing them securely and then use them to create a new login for impersonation purposes whenever you need it. If you can't, you're stuck with arranging delegation with vanilla Active Directory, which is neither easy nor flexible, certainly not if you want a work queue in the middle.

Comment: Thank you! Can you add this as an answer to my question? I think it will be good to point out that this is a god-forgotten mess to implement and better use modern authentication methods. For whoever decide to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impersonation is not a native feature of any queueing system I’m aware of - MSMQ in particular does not offer this functionality.

I’m taking the scenario where you have an asynchronous service that Requires impersonation to a back end service you do not control (e.g. an SMB share or another service which requires windows auth). If you do control the back-end service, consider allowing your service to authenticate as itself then “act as” the real client.

So, under the assumption you need real impersonation, you have a couple options: [S4U](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/08/28/logon-as-a-user-without-a-password/) and [C2WTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539739(v%3Doffice.14)). Both are essentially ways to use SeTcbPrivilege to issue tokens for users by username (no password required). A good [tutorial of both technologies is available on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649317(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

If that doesn’t immediately trigger the warning bells, it should be noted that this would be a very security critical piece of code. SeTcbPrivilege by itself only affects the local machine and is therefore manageable, but if used in combination with delegation it can be used to access remote resources with the same privileges as the caller. You essentially are running your service with “domain admin” rights unless constrained and planned very carefully.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. Now I have more understanding of current/old problems in windows in this field.